# How acomplish a result from third Inner Join in mySQL- statement

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL database.

I run this question today

```
SELECT t1.catalogID, t2.antfrp, t1.Latin, t1.Popular
FROM `mydb`.`products` T1
INNER JOIN `mydb`.`packages` T2 ON T1.catalogID = T2.catalogID
WHERE T1.Spring = 1
AND T1.lager + T1.sold > 0
AND (T2.packtyp = "L" OR T2.packtyp = "P")
```

It results in a several thousand rows long RecordSet. In the same RecordSet - I want this question from a third table to be included as an extra field in each row

```
SELECT SUM(Numitems)
from oitems
WHERE
    catalogid = (the actual one for each row) AND
    orderid > 25746 AND (packtyp = "L" OR packtyp = "P") AND
    numitems = 1
```

and have for that purpose made a third Inner JOIN like this

```
INNER JOIN `mydb`.`oitems` T3
    ON T3.catalogid = T2.catalogID
```

And altered my SELECT to

```
SELECT t1.catalogID, t2.antfrp, t1.Latin, t1.Popular, (SELECT SUM(T3.Numitems)
from oitems AS T3
WHERE T3.orderid > 25746 AND
    (T3.packtyp = "L" OR T3.packtyp = "P") AND T3.numitems = 1)
```

However - that is not the correct way to do it - and I feel stucked and can not wrap my head around how to accomplish this - Can someone with a better MySQL understanding perhaps see where I go wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join and do the fact you are using aggregation function you should use group by for `t1.catalogID, t2.antfrp, t1.Latin, t1.Popular`

```
SELECT SUM(T3.Numitems) , t1.catalogID, t2.antfrp, t1.Latin, t1.Popular
FROM `mydb`.`products` T1
INNER JOIN `mydb`.`packages` T2 ON T1.catalogID = T2.catalogID
INNER JOIN oitems T3 ON T3.catalogid = T1.catalogid 
WHERE T1.Spring = 1
AND T1.lager + T1.sold > 0
AND (T2.packtyp = "L" OR T2.packtyp = "P")
AND T3. orderid > 25746 AND (T3.packtyp = "L" OR T3.packtyp = "P") AND T3.numitems = 1
GROUP BY t1.catalogID, t2.antfrp, t1.Latin, t1.Popular
```

Comment: Brilliant - working like a charm and is now used in our production line for labelling products. For me it was also easy to put in a 4th Inner Join to use jet another WHERE - clause from jet another table - Thanks scaisEdge

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to join to a subquery on the third table:

```
SELECT
    t1.catalogID,
    t2.antfrp,
    t1.Latin,
    t1.Popular,
    t3.numitems
FROM products t1
INNER JOIN packages t2
    ON t1.catalogID = t2.catalogID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT catalogID, SUM(Numitems) AS Numitems
    FROM oitems
    WHERE
        orderid > 25746 AND
        (packtyp = 'L' OR T3.packtyp = 'P') AND
        numitems = 1
    GROUP BY catalogID
) t3
    ON t2.catalogID = t3.catalogID
WHERE
    t1.Spring = 1 AND
    t1.lager + t1.sold > 0 AND
    (t2.packtyp = 'L' OR t2.packtyp = 'P');
```

Comment: Perfectly working solution - Thanks - However I chosed to go with scaisEdge - s solution since it was easier to put in a 4th Inner Join (for me)

Comment: @Knoelen Check the performance of both approaches.  I believe this approach would generally perform better.

Comment: I dont think performance is of great importance in this case, but might just be unaware??  Anyway - how would I check the performance?

Comment: Run both queries and see which one takes longer?  If you are dealing with small data sets then it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Both ran on ~0,2  s with a tendency of the other solution being slightly faster